# angularjs promises: then called before deferred.resolve() in timeout

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have code similar to the below. It should print "in intermediate then" and afterward "in final then", but it prints the "in final then" first (i.e. the then function is getting called before the deferred.resolve() is called). Any idea why this could be happening? Does it have to do with the $timeout?

```
var promise = myFunctionThatReturnsAPromise();
promise.then(function() {
  console.log('in final then!');
});

var myFunctionThatReturnsAPromise = function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $timeout(function() {
      console.log('in intermediate then');
      deferred.resolve();
   }, 0);
   return deferred.$promise;
};
```

Comment: Does it still happen if you change the timeout length? I think it has something to do with angular flushing the timeout queue as well as promise queue in the same tick.

Comment: Alternatively, I believe setTimeout operates independently of the digest cycle, so might be more reliable for what you're looking for.

Comment: should be `return deferred.promise`. Also, in this particular case, you don't need another promise - just return the promise generated by `$timeout` - `return $timeout(function(){...})`

Comment: Good point @NewDev. OK, so the problem did turn out to be deferred.promise vs deferred.$promise. What is the difference?

Comment: There is no `$promise` - so you were returning `undefined`. Your code was just breaking (check the console)

Comment: Missed that issue. Should've tried the code :)

Comment: Ok so my code wasn't actually breaking b/c I had returned a $resource object in my actual code whose promise is actually $promise. So an unlucky coincidence. Thanks for the help. I'm going to mark Vlad Lego's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should return `deferred.promise`, without the `$`.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yhQXiiTnrCH6fTZVAC1g?p=preview)